# Cannot use my own polyfill for React Native Object.assign

Tags: reactjs, react-native, polyfills

Due to this issue https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/9773229227895bfc5a5bde969108a4cbcc270eab#diff-ce1179d24387784c3c5f856c4b5b55d8R59

`Object.assign` fails on dev builds for RN under certain scenarios (which is explained in the above link's comments). The issue is that one of my node modules triggers this particular scenario. I need to polyfill for that reason.

I'm trying to polyfill my own `Object.assign` (based on this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/Libraries/polyfills/Object.es6.js, except without the check for an existing one)

When I log out `global` from within the node module, I can see that it is pointing to my code

```
Object: ƒ Object()
arguments: (...)
assign: ƒ assign(target, varArgs)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 2
name: "assign"
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: objectAssign-polyfill.js:2
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[1]
```

However, the node module still appears to be using its own `Object.assign` rather than my polyfilled one.

When I modify the code in the node module to use `global.Object.assign`, it seems to finally work. However, is there a way to do this without doing that (because then I'd have to do it everywhere)?

The code is below:

```
// objectAssign-polyfill.js
Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    value: function assign(target, varArgs) {
        'use strict';
        if (target == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
        }

        let to = Object(target);

        for (let index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
            let nextSource = arguments[index];

            if (nextSource != null) {
                for (let nextKey in nextSource) {
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
                        to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return to;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});

// shims.js
import "node-libs-react-native/globals";
import './objectAssign-polyfill'
import { btoa } from "Base64";
import nodeUrl from 'url';

global.btoa = btoa;
global.URL = class URL {
    constructor(url) {
        return nodeUrl.parse(url)
    }
}

// index.js (the root of my RN app)
/** @format */
import "./shims";
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import Core from "./Core";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Core);
```